# How does pip wheel resolves transitive dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-wheel

When I run `pip wheel sentry-sdk` it downloads the following wheel files:

1. `certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
2. `sentry_sdk-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
3. `urllib3-1.25.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Where `sentry_sdk-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` is the lib I actually want to use and the other ones are transitive dependencies required by this lib to work. I understand that the file is coming from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/sentry-sdk/0.18.0/) however what I do not understand is how `pip wheel` is choosing the version of the aforementioned transitive dependencies.

### More Context

My underlying problem is that the resolved version of the `urllib3` clashes with another one already added to the pex file of the project I'm working on (I'm using Bazel to generate the pex) I'm considering  downgrading the version of `urllib3` to match my project's existing one. Looking at the [`setup.py` from the `sentry-sdk` in GitHub](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/master/setup.py) it says it only requires it to be greater than `1.10.0` (`"urllib3>=1.10.0"`) so I think the downgrade would work but I wanted to be sure to avoid production crashes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the current version of pip (2020-10-13) [does not have a dependency resolver](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988), it picks the first constraint greedily (so if `urllib3` is encountered unbounded first, it will pick the latest version -- even if a later package has a more restrictive requirement)

this is being changed in pip, you can [enable the resolver as an opt-in in pip>=20.2](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988#issuecomment-666464268) and it will become the default in the future (later this year)